# Powerapps dropdown choice filtering

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I am creating an application with connection to two sharepoint list. Here what the table look like

```
**EmailManager**
ID  EmailTemplate         EmailTemplateID   Send       From....
1   orientationTemplate   1                 2022-16-03
```

```
**EmailTemplate**
ID  Title                 HtmlBody    Approved
1   orientationTemplate   ...         true
```

Has you may notice EmailManager.EmplateTemplate refer to the title and EmailManager.EmailTemplateID refer to the id and its a lookup form. The issue that I have is I would like in powerapps the field called Email Template that would show me a dropdown of all the email template, with a filtering. The filtering is select all EmailTemplate with Approved= true.

This is what I have and its not quite right, this is build using a edit form

Original
 `Choices([@EmailManager].EmailTemplate)`

MyFormulas
 `Filter(Choices([@EmailManager].EmailTemplate),ThisItem.Approved=true)`

Now i am fairly new to powerapps, but i am not sure if its the right approach( i have seen some option where you build a collection of your options, but this seem hard for no reason)

PS: to be fair i am bit confused has to why would it point EmailManager and not EmailTemplate
`Filter(Choices([@EmailTemplate].Title),ThisItem.Approved=true)`  something like this would make more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's easier to just have 2 lists that are not linked as lookup columns. I'd remove them personally and use it as follows.
You can filter lists with the Filter options. If you use it for drop down then you would want to do something like in the items property:

If your status field is a choice column in sharepoint:

```
Filter(EmailTemplate, Status.value = true)
```

If text field:

```
Filter(EmailTemplate, Status = "true")
```

Then use ID for the value option.

Create a text field in the form for EmailManager and set the default value of the EmailTemplateID textfield to DropDownBox.Selected.ID or DropDownBox.Selected.Value.